# How do get Msys or Mingw utilities and msysgit to work together?

Tags: git, mingw-w64, msysgit, msys

I have a windows dev environment our team members download that has an older version of msysgit and a bunch of the unix msys utilities ( zip, awk, bison, etc ) which we use so our builds run on both linux and windows.

Well the git is now old enough that git hub no longer supports it as well as other newer repositories.

If I install the available "MSys64 for windows 10 download" and also the MSysGit for windows 64 download I find they are not compatible as they seem to have conflicting DLLs or some such problem where I can't run both from the same shell.

Is there a version of MSys or MinGW that includes git and the unix like utilities so both can be in the path under the same "bash" shell ?  that would be ideal.  Or is there a way to ensure I have two compatible systems.

Ideally so I can tell a team member to download the bin folder on a windows 10 64 bit box, set permissions.  Download the source, execute the build script and it works.

Comment: Use msys2. Link: http://www.msys2.org/

Answer (score 1):

Simply uncompress the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) portable archive [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then setup a simplified path in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

(Add any other path you would need)

And type `bash`: you will be in a shell with 200+ Linux commands, and Git itself.

The other approach is to activate [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), in which you can install a regular Git for Linux, and benefit from *all* Linux commands, without limitation.

Comment: Thanks - I believe I tried this one but it appeared to be missing unix command ws present in my current msysgit area ( 5 year old version )  where all commands and Git are available in the bash shell. 

will report back.

Comment: so far seems to work fine except the first time I run bash it responds with:

mkdir: cannot change permissions of '/dev/shm': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot change permissions of '/dev/mqueue': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\protocol' -> '/etc/protocols'
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services' -> '/etc/services'
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\networks' -> '/etc/networks'
msys


I tried running the install as administrator and no change.

Comment: the permission error doesn't seem to break anything

But though the "unzip" command is present the "zip" command is NOT and our build scripts use zip to create jar files and other archives.

Are there additional commands that can be installed somehow?

Comment: @peterk yes, I realize the PATH I mention is not complete: I have edited the answer.

Comment: yeah noticed.  "zip" isn't in there either.  I did find I got everything to work if I took the old zip.exe and the old msys-1.0.dll into usr/bin.  I wonder why they took it out? many archove and "dist" formats are based on zip files and the windows zip has nasty argument syntax needing special cases and a few other issues.

Comment: @peterk You don't need zip though. http://www.peazip.org/ 7z.exe would be enough to decode *any* archive format (including zip)

Comment: I'll check it out - what is nice is the old msys/bin/zip.exe used almost the same argument format as Ubuntu.  The unzip works fine for decoding, this is for encoding.